# MS Access timeout getting a table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mysql-odbc-connector

I'm using MS Access as frontend (in Windows), MySQL Server as DB (in RedHat) and ODBC to connect both.
I use linked tables in Access.

I have a huge table and always I try to get it, throw an exception:
"ODBC--call failed.
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0 (w) Driver][mysqld-8.0.16] Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded (#3024)." (Always at 60 seconds)

I've tried everything. I can't find anything which can help me in the documentation or looking online.

I read post from years ago which mention to use "readtimeout or MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT" in the registry editor (regedit.exe) and nothing. In the documentation appear that this option are not available since version 5.1.12.

I have no idea what can I do to delete or increase the timeout. Help!

Versions:
MySQL Server: 8.0.16 (Running on RedHat 7.5),
MS Access 365 (Running on Windows 10),
MySQL ODBC 8.0.15

Comment: why your query is so slow ???? ..  you should investigate for this

Comment: Increcrese the time out readtimeout and see if you can optimize your query

Comment: Run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%'; and look for those set to 60. Also, check the odbc advanced options looking for connections or wait timeouts

Comment: It's a table with over 20 million records. I can't change that...
I have another table with over 8 million records which is displayed correctly. It doesn't display all the records at the same time, but it works.

I've tried with all the variables with '%timeout%' and nothing...

Answer (score 0):

ok, old question, but maybe someone ist still looking for an answer:
The timeout is not caused from (Mysql-)serverside. It is a clientside Microsoft Access limit. You can create in Access a query on the linked table and adjust in the query settings the ODBCTimeout property (defaults to 60sec).